# Twig template external url img

Tags: php, facebook, symfony, twig, fosfacebookbundle

I am trying to display image from facebook profile.

routing.yml

```
_graph_facebook:
path: graph.facebook.com/{fbId}/{var}
requirements:
    _scheme:  https
```

template.html.twig

What I get is **htpps://mydomain.local/graph.facebook.com/facebookId/picture** .

I was trying with assets but it works only if it's hardcoded.

```
{% image 'https://graph.facebook.com/'~app.user.facebookId~'/picture'%}
        <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

This code doesn't work it says that: Unexpected token "operator" of value "~".
I couldn't find answer probably it's vaery simply.Thanks for Your help

Comment: Routing for your app, not external services.

Comment: Can You please indicate External Service Routing in documentation.I could not find it.

Comment: I mean routing cannot be used for external urls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, the router only applies to the URLs of your website.

Anyway, you can simply display the image with the `facebookId` value:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ app.user.facebookId }}/picture" alt="Example" />
```

Comment: Thank You. I just saw somewhere in documentation a tip - good practice about routing shouldn't be hard-coded in template. But now it's clear.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't use routing for external URI management only internal.

If you want to encapsulate this "behavior" in a method/function accessible by twig i can suggest you to create a Twig_Method via an custom twig extension : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Answer (score 0):

Concatenation operator's ~ arguments should be space-char separated.

```
'https://graph.facebook.com/' ~ app.user.facebookId ~ '/picture'
```

External urls should be escaped with html_attr filter:

```
<img src="{{ asset_url|e('html_attr') }}" alt="Example" />
```